# Delete the terms that begin with `@` but iff they are at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have three sentences:

```
 x<-c("Hello @Ada how are you?","@Jack the weather is good", "Jack the weather is good")
```

I would like to delete the terms that begin with `@` but iff they are at the beginning of the sentence. For example, the desired result is:

```
"Hello @Ada how are you?"  "the weather is good" "Jack the weather is good"
```

Wih my code, instead, I obtained a different result:

```
>gsub("^@", "", x)
[1] "Hello @Ada how are you?"  "Jack the weather is good" "Jack the weather is good"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can to add `[^ ]* *`. Where `[^ ]*` is everything but not a space.

```
gsub("^@[^ ]* *", "", x)
#[1] "Hello @Ada how are you?"  "the weather is good"     
#[3] "Jack the weather is good"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use :

```
sub('^@\\w+\\s*', '', x)
#[1] "Hello @Ada how are you?"  "the weather is good"      "Jack the weather is good"
```

This deletes the first word that start with `'@'` along with the whitespace following it.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace first word starting with `@` upto the first space

```
> gsub("^@.*?\\ ", "", x)
[1] "Hello @Ada how are you?"  "the weather is good"      "Jack the weather is good"
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the metacharacter `^` to mark the first position in the string as well as `trimws`to remove unwanted whitespace:

```
trimws(sub("^@\\w+", "", x))
[1] "Hello @Ada how are you?"  "the weather is good" "Jack the weather is good"
```